# Save userinformation (username, age, etc) in Server.Cache instead of fetching from db

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

When a user login to my site I fetch some information about that user from the db:

- UserID
- Username
- Email
- etc

This information is then saved into FormsAuthentication with .SetAuthCookie.

Is this the fastest way to do this or what If I change so the information gets saved into System.Cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or what If I change so the information gets saved into System.Cache?

Then **all** users of your website will share the same information. So you totally don't want to be storing user specific information into the Cache. The userData portion of the FormsAuthentication cookie seems like an excellent place to store some user specific information which is used on all pages to avoid hitting your database on each page. Some people might also recommend you using the Session but I am not part of those people.

Comment: Really? Even if I create new Cache objects for every user?
Like: System.Cache["User1Info"], System.Cache["User2Info"] etc

Comment: No, if you use the username as key for the cache then it's fine. One drawback of the cache is that by default it is stored in the server memory. This means that if your website runs in a webfarm you might need to use a distributed cache so that all nodes of your farm share this information. This could be a little more difficult to setup. With cookies, the information is persisted on the client and you should not be bothered with it.